# ViewPager and recycleView image lost when click twice or come back fragment

Tags: java, android

I am using DrawerLayoutmenu with a ViewPager and recycleView  in my application and I have three tabs in it. I am using ViewPager and recycleView inside a fragment. Now my problem here is, the first time there is no error and when i come back fragment  CongThucFragment It looks like it was error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferencesToken=getSharedPreferences("DataChefy",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    TokenClass.Token = sharedPreferencesToken.getString("Token","");
    Log.d("MainActivity10",TokenClass.Token);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        fragmentClass = UserInfoFragment.class;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentClass = UserInfoFragment.class;
        try {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,(Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance(), "UserInfoFragment");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentClass = CongThucFragment.class;
        try {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,(Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance(), "CongThucFragment");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferencesToken.edit();
                editor.putString("Token","");
                editor.apply();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
public  boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

and this my fragment

```
public class CongThucFragment extends Fragment {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentActivity myContext;
static public CongThucFragment newInstance(){
    return new CongThucFragment();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    myContext = (FragmentActivity) context;
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onAttach(context);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmen_congthuc,container,false);
    tabLayout= (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsChampionDetail);
    viewPager= (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerChampionDetail);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager ) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());

    for(int i =1 ;i<=3.;i++) {
        if(i==1)adapter.addFragment(ChildrenCongthucFragment.newInstance("vn"), "Country  " + i + "");
        else if(i==2)adapter.addFragment(ChildrenCongthucFragment.newInstance("lao"), "Country  " + i + "");
        else adapter.addFragment(ChildrenCongthucFragment.newInstance("tay"), "Country  " + i + "");
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

fragment 2

```
public class ChildrenCongthucFragment extends Fragment{
String Country = null;
List<Congthuc> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerDataAdapter recyclerDataAdapter = null;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerNews;
static public ChildrenCongthucFragment newInstance(String country){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("mCountry",country);
    ChildrenCongthucFragment fragment = new ChildrenCongthucFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initializeData();


}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycle_children_congthuc,container,false);

    Country = getArguments().getString("mCountry");
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_photo_collection_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    recyclerDataAdapter =new RecyclerDataAdapter (view.getContext(),R.layout.recycle_children_congthuc,CountryFillter(Country,mItems));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerDataAdapter);
    return view;
}
private void initializeData(){
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("1", "banh mì","vn","http://giadinh.vcmedia.vn/k:2016/photo-0-1472785146823/nhungmonanngonchogiadinhdip29.jpg"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("2", "bánh gián","vn","http://toinayangi.vn/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/m%C3%B3n-%C4%83n-vi%E1%BB%87t-nam-n%E1%BB%95i-ti%E1%BA%BFng-g%E1%BB%8Fi-cu%E1%BB%91n.jpg"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("3", "bún","lao", "http://anh.eva.vn/upload/2-2016/images/2016-06-12/5-mon-an-ngon-tuyet-cho-cuoi-tuan-5-1465696055-width640height80.jpg"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("4", "phỏ", "lao","https://i0.wp.com/theboola.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/144837125.jpg?resize=506%2C341"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("5", "hủ tíu","tay", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_AWhsxDkMDqkIhPGSNLZj8TFAkF3pedEa6Tt-l72mSt6PdRXaEg"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("6", "cam","tay", "https://i.imgur.com/3M37NQM.jpg"));
    mItems.add(new Congthuc("7", "quýt","ta", "http://vnngon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cach-lam-mon-an-ngon-ga-nhoi-thap-cam-xoi-vnngon-2.jpg"));
}ArrayList<Congthuc> CountryFillter(String con,List<Congthuc> cts){

  List<Congthuc> Ncts = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0;i<cts.size();i++)
  {
      Congthuc ct = cts.get(i);
      if (con.equals(ct.getQuocGia()))
      {
          Ncts.add(ct);
      }
  }
  return (ArrayList<Congthuc>) Ncts;}}
```

my adapter

```
public class RecyclerDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Congthuc> congthucs;
private  int layout;
private Context context;
public RecyclerDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Congthuc> congthucs) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout=layout;
    this.congthucs = congthucs;
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgCT;
    TextView txtCT;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgCT= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image_View);
        txtCT= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);

    }

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_collection, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Congthuc congthuc = congthucs.get(position);
    holder.txtCT.setText(congthuc.getDescription());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(congthuc.getLink())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .resize(150,120)
            .centerCrop()
            .skipMemoryCache()
            .into(holder.imgCT);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return congthucs ==null?0:congthucs.size();
}}
```

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: my aplication not have log error ,in turn back fragmen image in recycle view not displayed